# DirectDraw Rendering Issues in Windows 8 in Legacy Code

Tags: c++, winapi, directdraw

I know almost nothing about DirectDraw and/or DirectX, but I've been helping port an old Windows 9x game to Windows 8. The game uses DirectDraw for rendering and on Windows 8 the GUI of the game has major artifacts.

Here is what the GUI **should** look like:
[image: Windows 7 running Underlight]

And here is the same build, running on Windows 8.1:
[image: Windows 8.1 runing Underlight]

I realize this isn't much to go on but I don't know what additional information I can provide that will help answer this question. I have access to the code, I can show you how we're loading bitmaps, initializing DirectDraw, whatever. But I don't know what bits are interesting.

Note this is an OLD Win32 API app; no MFC, no WPF, nothing but a plain old message pump.

Happy to provide any more information I can.g

Comment: Does the code implement proper error checking? Have you looked to see if any DX  calls are failing?

Comment: I believe it does; if any of the DDraw setup calls fail, the game will immediately exit.

Comment: What about the rendering calls?

Comment: No, but I think I may have found the issue. Windows 8 expects all bitmaps to be 32 bit, but ours are not. I expect it's making them all full alpha OR it's just misaligning the bits somehow.